# Help with somes series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate $f'(\pi)$ when

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{e^{-nt}\cdot\cos(nt)}{1}$$

Comment: Are you sure about dividing by $1$ ? That looks like a typo.

Comment: The crucial division by $1$...

Answer (score 2):

Since (assuming that weird division by $\;1\;$ is correct) :

$$\left|\frac{\cos nt}{e^{nt}}\right|\le\frac1{e^{nt}}$$

the series converges absolutely for $\;t>0\;$ and

$$f'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-n\sin nt-n\cos nt}{e^{nt}}\implies f'(\pi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{e^{n\pi}}=\frac{e^\pi}{\left(1+e^\pi\right)^2}$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Of course. Thanks, editing now.

Comment: Thanks, still can't se the last part. Can't see why the series is equal to the answer :S

Comment: Observe that $$1-\frac1{1+e^t}=\frac{e^{t}}{1+e^t}=S(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{ e^{nt}}\implies \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2}=S'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac n{e^{nt}}$$

Comment: Oh, never seen a series like that, been using my earlier calculus book... Do you know if there's a page where I can find "standard"-series?

Comment: Oh, and I just looked at the solutions, apparently there should be a "-1" at the denominator and not "+1"

Comment: Do you mean $\;-1+e^t\;$ in the denominator? I don't think so....but, of course, I could be wrong. And just google "geometric infintie series" and you'll get thousands of pages.\

Comment: Yea, according to the book I got. Great thanks, gonna check that out :)